# Python: Breaking query string into associative array not working

Tags: python, parsing, query-string, fastcgi, wsgi

This is a Python script to parse values from a query string.

The block inside app function works fine, when placed in a standalone Python script. But when placed in the app() function the values for **temperature, humidity, wind and time are empty** and that's wrong.

environ['QUERY_STRING'] can be "temperature=20&humidity=50&wind=30&time=morning"

This doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys, os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

import urlparse
import cgi

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])

    qs = environ['QUERY_STRING'] # EQUALS temperature=20&humidity=50&wind=30&time=morning
    parsed = cgi.parse_qs(qs) # tried both cgi and urlparse

    yield parsed['temperature']
    yield parsed['humidity']
    yield parsed['wind']
    yield parsed['time']

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py in write(data=['20'])
   1062 
   1063         def write(data):
=> 1064             assert type(data) is str, 'write() argument must be string'
   1065             assert headers_set, 'write() before start_response()'
   1066
```

This works:

```
qs = "temperature=20&humidity=50&wind=30&time=morning"
parsed = cgi.parse_qs(qs)
print parsed['temperature']
print parsed['humidity']
print parsed['wind']
print parsed['time']
```

Output:

```
['20']
['50']
['30']
['morning']
```

Comment: Does yielding fixed strings work?

Comment: That seems to be the problem, I need to aggregate and return the results.

Comment: So then the problem isn't the parsing, it's "How do I WSGI?".

Comment: Yes yielding fixed strings works @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the return value of app() should be an iterable.  I'm no WSGI expert so I've checked the fcgi source code to make sure.

Try it like this:

```
for k in ('temperature', 'humidity', 'wind', 'time'):
    yield parsed[k]
```

If each value is actually a list of values and you just want the first, as alluded to above, do it like this:

```
for k in ('temperature', 'humidity', 'wind', 'time'):
    yield parsed[k][0]
```

I have edited my answer because I said earlier that it was not ok to have multiple yields outside a loop.. I researched it and that was an incorrect statement on my part.  It is ok.. this is just a bit neater.

Or just return them as a simple list or tuple since the values are in memory already and are quite small.  The yield does not really buy you anything here.

Comment: When done like this it puts all values into one large string. Could be improved, but I like the solution.

Comment: if you want browser formatting in the response then you need to return html or other formatted output, not just the raw submitted values.  If you are trying to return data for ajax then use the json module to format your output.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned was an array, so using second dimmension index helped.

```
yield parsed['temperature'][0]
yield parsed['humidity'][0]
yield parsed['wind'][0]
yield parsed['time'][0]
```